# how to remove BuddyPress branding from website permalinks

Tags: buddypress

e.g. https://www.example.com/buddypress/members/admin/, how can I remove "Buddypress" branding from the URL?

I just want to remove the BuddyPress branding from my website permalinks.

Comment: No idea if thats configurable but they seem to have their own support forum here: https://buddypress.org/support/

Comment: BP does not add 'buddypress'  to urls.  Something in your install added it.  Check the page slugs too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this within the BuddyPress settings for specific BuddyPress directories, by assigning them to specific WordPress Pages you manually create.

1. Login to your wp-admin as an Admin user
2. Create a new blank Page representing the URL you want to use instead of "Members". For example, if you want the URL to be https://www.example.com/mem/membername, create a page called "mem" and set its permalink within WP to be /mem
3. Click Settings->BuddyPress->Pages
4. Select the "mem" page next to Members and click Save Settings